# Adding an additional email domain to Azure for Exchange Online: should we add a second domain or create a separate AAD tenant?

Tags: azure-active-directory, exchange-server

We currently have an Azure Active Directory tenant, which replicates via AD Connect our on-premises Windows users.  We have an on-premises Exchange Server where accounts are my-company.com.

We have another email domain my-company.io for which there are no users yet.

In the immediate future, we want to create a few mailboxes for my-company.io directly in Exchange Online (not on our Exchange Server).  These mailboxes will not be attached to Windows domain users.

Later this year, we want to start migrating our my-company.com Exchange mailboxes to Exchange Online, gradually with a hybrid setup.

In this scenario, what does make more sense?

a) Create second tenant in our Azure account, create there any my-company.io AAD users, then add these users to Exchange Online.

b) Add another domain to our existing tenant, create there any my-company.io AAD users, then add these users to Exchange Online.

Our concern is if activating Exchange Online for my-company.io users in the existing tenant, will interfere in any way our future plan to migrate to Exchange Online for my-company.com users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods should be feasible. The difference is whether the two accounts exist under the same tenant. If you have a reason to let them exist under the same tenant, you should choose the second option. But if you do not require them to exist under the same tenant, creating a new tenant for `my-company.io` is recommended, because this will reduce the configuration when migrating to Exchange Online for `my-company.com` users.

Your concern is not superfluous, but they are not unsolvable. If you choose the second option, then you need to carefully design what your hybrid deployment environment is like. For example, there are two types of users, one is a hybrid deployment user, and the other is a cloud-only user. You can refer to [this document](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-merge-an-office-365-account-with-an-on-premises-ad-account-after-hybrid-configuration/) to choose the configuration you need.

In short, from the perspective of easy configuration and management of different types of users, the first solution is better, while the second solution does not require you to create new tenants and requires you to pay more attention to configuring hybrid deployments.